# Spark structured streaming of csv ignoring rows while writing dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

**Spark version**=Apache Spark 3.3.0

I'm using spark structured streaming to read and process comma-delimited CSV files.
 However, some records automatically get dropped in the target table, I'm assuming this is happening due to a column value having lots of character in it.

**Edited**: Read DF is reading data correctly, but at the time of writing the DF, a few rows get removed

The following comma-delimited row is a row that gets dropped automatically and there is more like this.

```
a500o0000008bugAAA,FALSE,KMI000004704,Key Medical Insight,0050o00000WuoSBAAZ,2020-04-02T10:17:02.000Z,0019000000R3GVDAA3,4/2/2020,"<XXXX XXXXX=XXXXX-XXXXX: XXX-XXXX;>XXXXXXXXXX XXXX XXXXXXX XXXX XX XXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXX-XX. XXXXXX XXX XXX XXXXXXXXX XXX XXXXX XXXXXXXXXX XXXX XXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXX XXX XXXX XXXXXXXX XX XXXXXXXXXX XXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXX XX XXXXX XXXXX. XXXXXXXX XXXX XXXX XX XXXXX XXXXX XXXXXXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXX-XX XXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX XXX XXXXXXX XXXX XXXXXXX XXXXXX XX XXXX XXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX XXX XXXXXXX XXXXX XXX. </XXXX><XXX><XXXX XXXXX=XXXXX-XXXXX: XXX-XXXX;><XX></XXXX></XXX><XXX><XXXX XXXXX=XXXXX-XXXXX: XXX-XXXX;>XXXXXXXXX XXXX XXXXXXX&#XX;X XX.X XXXXX XXXXXXXXX (XXX-XXXXXXXX) XXXXX XXX XXXX XXXXXXXX XXXX X XXXXXXXX - XXXX XXXXXXXX XX XXXXXX XXX (XXXXXX XXXX XXXXX XXX XXXXX) XX XXXX-XX-XXXX XXXXX XXX XXXXXXX XXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX XXX XXXXXXXXXX (XXXX XXX XXXXXXXX XXXXX). 

XXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX XXXX XXXXXXXX XX XXXXXX XXX XXXXXX XXXX XXXX XX XXXXX XXXXXXX X.X. &XXXX;XXXXXXXX XXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXX XXXXXXXXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX&XXXX;. </XXXX><XXX><XXXX XXXXX=XXXXX-XXXXX: XXX-XXXX;><XX></XXXX></XXX><XXX><XXXX XXXXX=XXXXX-XXXXX: XXX-XXXX;>XXXXX XXXXXXXXXX: XXXXXXX XXXXXXX XX XX XXXXX XXXXXXXXXXX XXXXX XXXXXXXXXX XX XXXX XXXXXXXXXX XX XXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXX XXX XXXXXXX XX XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXX XX XXXX XXXXXXXXXX XXXXX XX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXX XXX XX X XXXXX XXXX XXXX XXX XXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX XX XXXXXXXXXX XXXXX XXXXXXXXX. XX XXXXXXXX XXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX XXX XXXXX XXXXXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXX-XX XXXXXX XXXXXXX XX XX XXXXX XXXX XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXX XXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXX - XXXXXX XX XXX.</XXXX></XXX></XXX>",a040o00002QZ26mAAD,Submitted_vod,Local Data/ Fact/Observation,Key Opinion Leader,Hematology
```

***note***: The field with the "xxxxx" values is a single field having lots of spaces and characters etc.

I read the CSV file through the following code

```
def read_stream(container_read_path, file_format, delimeter, spark, header):   
 spark.conf.set("spark.sql.streaming.schemaInference", True)
 source_data = (
    spark.readStream.format(file_format)
    .option("header", header)
    .option("sep", delimeter)
    .option("escape", "\"")
    .option("multiline", True)
    .option("recursiveFileLookup", "true")
    .load(f"{container_read_path}")
 )    
 return source_data
```

The following code use to save the structured streaming data

```
def write_stream(dataframe, database_name, table_name, checkpoint_path, partition_cols, 
header, file_format='parquet'):

 (dataframe
  .writeStream
  .format(file_format)
  .trigger(once=True)
  .option("checkpointLocation", f'{checkpoint_path}')
  .foreachBatch(lambda df, epochId: write_raw_file(df, epochId, database_name, 
   table_name, partition_cols, header, file_format))
  .start()
  )

def write_raw_file(df, epochId, database_name, table_name, partition_cols, header, 
file_format):
 file_format = 'csv' if file_format == 'text' else file_format
 header = "true" if file_format == 'csv' else "false"

 (df.write
  .mode("append")
  .option("header", header)
  .partitionBy(partition_cols)
  .format(file_format)
  .saveAsTable(f"{database_name}.{table_name}")
  )
```

Comment: Can you share by dropped do you mean they are not read in the source data or if they are dropped after df is written? Also, share the results after reading from hive and reading the parquet directly from the spark. Is the data missing in both?

Comment: At the time of reading, data is displaying correctly in DF, but it gets dropped while written into the parquet file.

Comment: I'm reading a CSV file and the CSV file gets written as parquet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by adding "option(multiLine, True)" to the write df.

```
def write_raw_file(df, epochId, database_name, table_name, partition_cols, 
header, file_format):
  file_format = 'csv' if file_format == 'text' else file_format
  header = "true" if file_format == 'csv' else "false"

  (df.write
   .mode("append")
   .option("header", header)
   .option("multiline", True)
   .partitionBy(partition_cols)
   .format(file_format)
   .saveAsTable(f"{database_name}.{table_name}")
   )
```

What happing is that the column with the value "xxxx" has lots of spaces characters and multiple lines, spark ignores the rows which span multiple lines. I'm required to add "option(multiLine, True)" to both read df and write df to get the desired result.

There is missing information in the documentation of spark read CSV which is
significant to highlight that "option(multiLine, True)" is can be used in write df as well.
[image]